# Счетчик в jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, html, html5

Как сделать счетчик в Jquery+HTML? Ну сколько голосов, рейтинга.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Какой вопрос, такой и ответ..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $('#votes').html('<b>1</b> голос');
 $('#rates').html('<b>1%</b> рейтинга');
</script>
```

Comment: А как 2,3,4???

Comment: @MrGons18, эмм. Замените 1 на 2...